# Why is this Array undefined and how to fix?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, undefined

I have a problem with my Code. It says that my Array is undefined but a method later it works fine. Here's the code:

```
books: IBook[] = [];
[...]
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getEmployees().subscribe(
      (listBooks) => this.books = listBooks,
      (err) => console.log(err)
    ); 
  }
[...]
 events: CalendarEvent[] = [
    {
      start: new Date(),
      end: new Date(),
      title: ""+this.books[0].device, //this.books[0] is undefined
      color: colors.yellow,
      actions: this.actions,
      resizable: {
        beforeStart: true,
        afterEnd: true
      },
      draggable: true
    },
[...]
test(){                     //this method is linked to a button
  console.log(this.books[0]) //after clicking it works fine
}
[...]
```

The Test method is after the array, where it says it's 'undefined' so it cant be undefined can it?

Comment: `getEmployees` is async, `this.books` will be assigned only after some time.

Comment: books: any = [];  <== try this code

Comment: @ErAbdulMeman thanks for ur answer but it didn't work

Comment: @RobertoZvjerkovic do u know how to fix it maybe?

Comment: Try this code may be it will work  --- Replace this title: ""+this.books[0].device, ==> title: this.books[0]?" "+this.books[0].device:' '

Comment: ```title:this.books[0]?" "+this.books[0].device:' '```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you doing this in your code ? :

```
 events: CalendarEvent[] = [
    {
      start: new Date(),
      end: new Date(),
      title: ""+this.books[0].device, //this.books[0] is undefined
      color: colors.yellow,
      actions: this.actions,
      resizable: {
        beforeStart: true,
        afterEnd: true
      },
      draggable: true
    },
[...]
```

If this code is in the ngOnInit method, you should put it in the subscribe callback like this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getEmployees().subscribe(
      (listBooks) => {
         this.books = listBooks
         [...]
         events: CalendarEvent[] = [
        {
          start: new Date(),
          end: new Date(),
          title: ""+this.books[0].device, //this.books[0] is undefined
          color: colors.yellow,
          actions: this.actions,
          resizable: {
          beforeStart: true,
          afterEnd: true
         },
         draggable: true
        },
        [...]
      },
      (err) => console.log(err)
    ); 
  }
```

The call of getEmployees is asynchronous which means that the events object may be initialized before the callback function where the books object gets initialized.
Hope it is clear

Comment: Hey @lchraf, this code isn't in any method the array is like a variable

Comment: Hey. Same answer then. Your events array gets initialized before books is filled. this statement title: ""+this.books[0].device should be done after the the books property gets filled. So you can eather do as I suggested in my answer or keen events in your component body with title empty : title: "" and then in the subscribe callback, fill the title

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `getEmployees()` running in the `ngOnInit` is async. The browser continues executing `events` assignment synchronously but the `listBooks` will be resolved from the call at some point later.

Therefore you should fix you logic and initialize `events` after your data are resolved and maybe handle that information you're expecting in case it's undefined:

```
title: this.books[0] ? ""+this.books[0].device : ""
```

Lastly, you need an immutable operation on the `books` when you want to assign the new data:

```
this.books  = [...listBooks]
```